ActivityLifecycleCallbacks not working with activities launched via implicit intents
There is any option to catch the activity lifecycle for activities that are launched via implicit intents?
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "http://...")
startActivity(intent)

Seems that ActivityLifecycleCallbacks is not working.
